# Oracle bulk updates using ODP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net

Looking at [this example](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/BulkOperationsUsingOracleDataProviderForNETODPNET.aspx) to do bulk inserts, I assumed using the same logic would work for updates. I tried to the following to see if it would work, and it does not:

```
string sql = "update TEST set NAME=:newName where NAME=:name";

connection.Open();
OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = sql;
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
command.BindByName = true;

command.ArrayBindCount = 5;

string[] originalName = { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5" };
string[] newName = { "New Test1", "New Test2", "New Test3", "New Test4", "New Test5" };

command.Parameters.Add(":newName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, originalName, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);
command.Parameters.Add(":name", OracleDbType.Varchar2, newName, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Does this not work for updates? Is there a way to easily do bulk updates similarly how the bulk inserts are performed in the example I linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had my parameter names flipped. Took me forever to find it.

Answer (score 0):

you cant pass a array as a parameter.

What you can do is loop through your array and call the update for each position of the array (whihc wouldnt really be a "bulk" insert), or you can use something like:

```
WHERE NAME in ("Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5")
```

and so on

Comment: Actually, you can. See my answer.

Comment: humm, interesting. What happens if the number of itens on both arrays are different?

Comment: Not sure. I would guess it would throw an exception.