# Bulk Update using query - C# and ORacle

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I am working in C#.Net and Oracle, Windows Application. In my dataset i am having around 1500 records. Using for loop, i need to update those records into database. The loop is executing correctly. For the first time, the first record got updated. whenever the loop goes for second row, nothing happens. I am not getting any error.

Here is my update code

```
log.Debug("Update Starts..");
            OracleTransaction oraTransaction = BeginTransaction();
            string Zip = string.Empty;
            StringBuilder updateSql = new StringBuilder();
            updateSql.Append("UPDATE STORE SET ");
            updateSql.Append(" LAT = ").Append("'").Append(Latitude).Append("'");
            updateSql.Append(" ,LONG = ").Append("'").Append(Longitude).Append("'");
            updateSql.Append(" ,LOCATION_TYPE = ").Append("'").Append(locationType).Append("'");
            updateSql.Append(" ,UPDATE_TIMESTAMP = ").Append("'").Append(PopulatedDate).Append("'");
            updateSql.Append(" WHERE ");
            updateSql.Append(" STR_ID = ").Append("'").Append(StoreID).Append("'");
            int result =  OracleHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(ConnectionString, CommandType.Text, updateSql.ToString());
            CommitTransaction(oraTransaction);
            EndTransaction(oraTransaction);
            CloseConnection(oracleConnection);
            log.Debug("Update Ends.." + result);
            return 1;
```

Comment: You might want to look into parameterized SQL and multi-line string literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only do one update in each loop and you are doing 1500 loops then I would suggest skipping the Transaction and also the closing of the Connection in each loop.

```
log.Debug("Update Starts..");
StringBuilder updateSql = new StringBuilder();
updateSql.Append("UPDATE STORE SET ");
updateSql.Append(" LAT = ").Append("'").Append(Latitude).Append("'");
updateSql.Append(" ,LONG = ").Append("'").Append(Longitude).Append("'");
updateSql.Append(" ,LOCATION_TYPE = ").Append("'").Append(locationType).Append("'");
updateSql.Append(" ,UPDATE_TIMESTAMP = ").Append("'").Append(PopulatedDate).Append("'");
updateSql.Append(" WHERE ");
updateSql.Append(" STR_ID = ").Append("'").Append(StoreID).Append("'");
int result =  OracleHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(ConnectionString, CommandType.Text, updateSql.ToString());
log.Debug("Update Ends.." + result);
return 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464616/oracle-bulk-updates-using-odp-net) question. It's doing exactly what you need, but way more efficient and secure. Follow the links provided there to learn more about bulk operations.

Comment: Can you post code? I have a hard time imagining you tried it and got the same problems.